# Failed to load API definition

Tags: swagger

Anyone can help me i am getting error in my magento 2 swagger.
https://api.backoffice-staging.kamioun.com/
Please let me know if anybody have solution for it.
Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems the request to `https://backoffice-staging.kamioun.com/rest/all/schema?services=all` is throwing an error:

> The "OrderInterface" class doesn't exist and the namespace must be specified. Verify and try again."

Fix this error and it should work. Looks like it's maybe be thrown from `Kamioun\Orders` if you have any modules like this in that namespace? Seems to just be a call to `OrderInterface` without the class being imported/full namespace declared.

Comment: Thanks Liam Toohey,

Comment: @VipinKumar If my response helped, could you please mark is as your answer? I'd appreciate it